# Reporting on 'over scoped' members

Tags: c#, continuous-integration, build-automation, visibility

I am working on a product which is highly extensible, and has an SDK. Something that we must keep a check on, is that member and class visibility is not greater than required. The higher the visibility of a member of an assembly, the more 'maintenance' it incurs.

I would like a tool that can generate a report as part of the nightly build, which by analysing the assemblies, can tell me if anything has been introduced that is 'overly visible' - i.e. is marked as public/protected, but is only used within same assembly... and so on.

Is there anything out there that can do this?
I have looked at NDepend, but its very complicated, and I couldnt craft a CQL expression that did what I wanted.

Comment: ReSharper does this for you interactively, and can give you a list of all problems across the entire solution, including over-scoped members.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Analyze your code with NDepend, then in the [Code Rules and Queries over LINQ](http://www.ndepend.com/Features.aspx#CQL) Explorer panel see the *Visibility* group. This group contains several CQLinq rules that warn about *over scoped* types and members:

[image: Visibility group]

These rules include:

- [Methods that could have a lower visibility](http://www.ndepend.com/DefaultRules/webframe.html?Q_Methods_that_could_have_a_lower_visibility.html)
- [Types that could have a lower visibility](http://www.ndepend.com/DefaultRules/webframe.html?Q_Types_that_could_have_a_lower_visibility.html)
- [Fields that could have a lower visibility](http://www.ndepend.com/DefaultRules/webframe.html?Q_Fields_that_could_have_a_lower_visibility.html)

Such rule can be [checked live in VisualStudio](http://www.ndepend.com/Doc_VS_CQL.aspx) or in a [report produced during nightly build CI process](http://www.ndepend.com/Doc_CI_Report.aspx#CQLRule). Running such a rule live in VS looks like:

[image]